# rescale xticks on multiple y-axis plot

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I have many questions about plotting using PGFplot,

1. How to re-scale the `xticks` for multiple y plots?!
2. How to move the .10(-2) a little bit to the right so it appears aligned?
3. How to change the `xtickslabel`?

   When I use `xtickslabel={1992,1993,1994,1995,1996}` I get each single tick with the 5 years as it appears in the second picture.

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 3,horizontal sep =1.5cm,vertical sep =1.5cm},height=6.5cm,width=8cm]
 \nextgroupplot[legend pos=north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        scaled ticks=false,
        y tick label style={anchor=east},   
                 ytick pos=left,
        scaled ticks=true,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=120,       
        xticklabel=\empty,
        ]
                \addlegendimage{empty legend}
                \addplot[red, mark=+]  table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAPbjh1.dat};
        \addlegendentry{Graphite}            
              \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 3,horizontal sep = 1.5cm,vertical sep =1.5cm},height=6.5cm,width=8cm
]
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={Pression Relative p/p$°$}, legend pos=north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        scaled ticks=false, %enlever le.10^-5 !!!!!!!!!!!!
        y tick label style={anchor=west},       
        xmin=0,
        xmax=110,  % I JUST FOUND THIS WHEN POSTING THE CODE SO THE SCALE IS OK 
        yticklabel pos=right,
        ytick pos=right,    
        scaled ticks=true,  
        ]
                \addlegendimage{empty legend}
                 \addplot[green, mark=o]   table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAPbjh2.dat};
        \addlegendentry{Graphite}
```

for the scale I found the "solution", the 10^-2 is confusing me.

The code of the 3rd question about `xtickslabel`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xticklabel={1992;1993;1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012},
xlabel={2008},
stack plots=y,
ylabel= {Total credit},
scaled ticks=true,
]
\addplot [black] table{Annexes/resultats/herbicides.dat};
%\addplot table[x=date,y=account2] {plotdata/accounts.dat};
%\addplot table[x=date,y=account3] {plotdata/accounts.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Perhaps post the code of your plot. So we could help to improve it. Or tell me, if a screenshot of a working plot of mine would be ok as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately with that information we are not able to help you, because you didn't provide compile code like your data file. So I guess we will close this question as being unclear what you are asking ...